# Angular CLI service-worker for platform server?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker, angular-service-worker

### Context

I'm using the Angular CLI to build a server-side rendered app. In my `.angular-cli.json` file, I have 2 apps in the `apps` array, one for `"platform": "browser"` and one for `"platform:": "server"`, which is available in `1.3.x`. Currently, I use the option for service workers in my browser config:

**.angular-cli.json**

```
...
"platform": "browser",
"serviceWorker": true
...
```

### Question:

Should I use the `"serviceWorker": true` option for the `"platform": "server"` as well?

Thanks!